# Dropdown menu for Breadcrumb in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Goal:
Create a dropdown(using bootstrap's dropdown list) menu in breadcrumb for "Pictures"

Problem:
I have tried doing it by using bootstrap 3 but it didn't go so well

Info:
*The webpage today `(http://jsbin.com/yobizugeba/edit?html,output)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this menu yourself

```
<div class="container">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
 <ul class="dropdown">
  <li>12345</li>
  <li>12345</li>
 </ul>
</div>

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.container img:hover + .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look exactly to the original bread crumb when I use dropdown list.

Comment: Then you need custom css to this dropdown, show me please design your dropdown

Comment: Give me please image, how should looks your menu

Comment: The looks of the dropdown list is bootstrap's dropdownlist.

Comment: and the missing part is the there is no "/" between "Home" and "test".
In other word, the result of "Second" should have the same looks as the "first" in the source code "http://jsbin.com/fificubaxe/edit?html,output"

Comment: Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I understand)) need add to css this line

.breadcrumb .dropdown {display: inline-block)

Comment: ))
<style>
 .breadcrumb .dropdown {display: inline-block) - not ')' tru '}'
</style>

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and helping me!